# ‘pos’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Getting this error currently:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘std::string class_name(const std::type_info&)’:
main.cpp:43:45: error: ‘pos’ was not declared in this scope
  if (const size_t pos = name.find(prefix)); pos != string::npos)
```

I've been trying to mess around with this string but can't seem to get it to pass when I try to compile.

The code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

void horizontal_line(size_t n = 80)
{
    cout << endl << string(n, '-');
}

void pause(size_t n = 80)
{
    horizontal_line(n);
    cout << "\n[Enter] to continue.";
    cin.get();
}

string currency(const float& amount)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale(""));
    ss << showbase << put_money(amount * 100);
    return ss.str();
}

string class_name(const type_info& typeinfo)
{
    static const string prefix("class ");
    static const size_t length = prefix.size();

    string name(typeinfo.name ());
    if (const size_t pos = name.find(prefix)); pos != string::npos)
    name.erase(pos, length);
    return name;
}
```

Trying to get it to compile to show the output for a vehicle list but having some trouble with this portion, the output obviously wont compile at the moment with this error. (Obviously this isn't the full code)

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using? An initializing if won;t work prior to Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, this is probably what you meant to do:

```
size_t pos = name.find(prefix);

if(pos != string::npos)
    name.erase(pos, length);
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are trying to use to *declare* AND *initialize* `pos` inside the `if` statement:

```cpp
if (const size_t pos = name.find(prefix)); pos != string::npos)
```

Is valid only in C++17 and later.  Also, you have an erroneous `)` before the `;` that you need to remove, the correct statement is:

```cpp
if (const size_t pos = name.find(prefix); pos != string::npos)
```

For earlier versions of C++, you need to separate the *declaration* of `pos` from the `if` statement:

```cpp
const size_t pos = name.find(prefix);
if (pos != string::npos)
```

Alternatively, you can perform the *assignment* of `pos` inside the `if` statement, just not the *declaration*, however the syntax is slightly different:

```cpp
size_t pos;
if ((pos = name.find(prefix)) != string::npos)
```

Comment: I didn't even think about the nice C++17 feature to keep the scope to a minimum. It seems obvious that that was really what OP was going for.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve a semicolon directly after the if. So the 2nd time pos appears, it’s not in an if block which is the only place pos would be in scope.

Comment: If you're referring to this portion `if (const size_t pos = name.find(prefix)); pos != string::npos)` I get other errors if I take it out, says it expects ; before ) before pos